# Как просмотреть нужные файлы в папке?

Tags: php

Есть папка на сервере,там есть файлы,папки.вложенные папки,файлы в этих папках,мне нужно просмотреть все файлы в этой папке,как это реализовать в скрипте?Как вообще добраться до этой папки,если она например лежит в корне

Answer (score 0):

1. Просмотреть содержимое дериктории - scandir [Мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php)
2. Пхп может принимать как относительные пути так и статические. - пишете просто адрес папки.
3. скорее всего вы под линуксом, так что убедитесь что у юзера php есть права к этой папке, но на мой взгяд это большая уязвимость, храните файлы к которым должен получить доступ php в www///

Comment: scandir получает массив из содержимого только из одной папки к которой указан путь,а как вывести все файлы,в том числе во вложенных папках

Comment: пройдитесь циклом по всем вложеным папкам.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dir = '/path/to/dir'; // путь к директории

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it);
foreach($files as $file) {
  if ($file->isFile()){
    echo $file->getRealPath(), PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```